# java poi get Cell value using for Loop

Tags: java, apache-poi

currently we implement the poi instead of jxl, so now i want to get the cell content and passing into an method until the last row

code:

```
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("F:\\AUT.xlsx"));
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    for (int row = 1; row <= sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); row++) {
        String cellvalue = 
    }
```

inside the for loop collect the first row value and stored into an String variable and passing this value to an method, then loop continue upto the last row

Let me know how i can do with for loop

Comment: Read the javadoc: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getRow%28int%29, https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#getCell%28int%29, https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getStringCellValue%28%29

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you Google your question you will get thousands of examples of reading excel files in Apache POI.

If you're stuck on something or facing an issue try to debug/search and then explore javadocs for answers. If you still have issues come back here with all the details.

Just to give you a start, do something like this:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("MyExcel.xls"));
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
for (Iterator iterator = sheet.rowIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) iterator.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells(); i++) {
        XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(i);
        System.out.println(formatter .formatCellValue(cell));
    }

}
```

Comment: Using [DataFormatter](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html) to get the "string" value of the cell would probably be better advice, as that'll cope well with numbers, dates etc

Comment: Creating the DataFormatter once, outside of the loop, and using it inside would be a tiny bit quicker, but there's not much in it!

Comment: @Gagravarr , yes it will.

Comment: This will fail if your data does not start in column 1 or has missing cells. See my answer for a better looping technique.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over cells more effectively, try the for each syntax:

```
for (Row r : sheet) {
    for (Cell c : r) {
        ... do something
    }
}
```

This will skip missing cells, and if your data does not start at column 1, it won't throw an error.